# How to use MVC to generate templated HTML from PHP

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller, html-generation

I have fairly complex HTML document to generate that is of the form

`<head> (a css that needs to be inserted here) </head>`

And a body with several flavors of templated bits of HTML.  Simplistically, I'd probably have one PHP function (let's pretend the domain is news articles since that's simplest) like

```
generateNewsBlob($title, $author, $imageSrc)
showUserInfo($userInfoStruct)
//etc.
```

that will output HTML with the arguments filling in the templates.

At minimum I just want a nice folder with easy to edit PHP and easy to edit HTML and CSS.  As of now I have it all smooshed together in a .php file - something like 
`'lots of HTML <img src="' . $imgSrc . "'> more HTML ...'`  which makes it very hard for our designer to make modifications and our coder (that'd be me) to make modifications.  So I need this to be decoupled.  But I'm not sure how to have a pure html file that has "holes" to be filled in by the php, because I would implement those holes in PHP...  catch-22.

It's been suggested in a previous SO question that MVC is the way to accomplish this.  This sounds believable but I have no actual idea how to go about this.  I can't bring in any IDE - a developer should be able to work on this in a text editor from console.

Python and Java are also options if those would happen to be "better."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of MVC frameworks for PHP and other platforms. http://www.phpwact.org/php/mvc_frameworks There are lots of benefits to using those but if you want something simpler, you can just use a PHP templating engine http://www.smarty.net/

Comment: I would suggest Twig over Smarty.

Comment: Twig was really easy to get to example templates and PHP code to do exactly what I want, so I will use that API, because that's how picking an API works.